How to interpret the cost for both items?
I am a little confused on the exact meaning of the following statement describing the price of two different items.

The cost is $10 for both.

Would that indicate that both items together cost $10 or is each item priced at $10 individually?

'Both' is used to refer to two people or things together so by the normal dictionary meaning, for $10 you get the two items. If the price was $10 for each item, that is what should have been said in the statement (i.e. 'The cost is $10 for each').

Put another way, both is the pair. Paying $10 for the pair means you pay $10 and you just bought them.

This wording definitely leans toward the meaning that $10 is the total price.

A more ambiguous wording would be:

Both are $10.

In that case it would be impossible to be sure of the intended meaning (partly because people employ verbal agreement somewhat unpredictably for collective terms!).
A fully unambiguous wording would be:

It's $10 for the two of them.

And an unambiguous wording of the opposite meaning would be:

They're $10 each.


Someone might argue that by the dictionary definition the original sentence is unambiguous, but in practice people do sometimes substitute "both" for "each" when not speaking carefully.

"in practice people do sometimes substitute "both" for "each" when not speaking carefully." But when writing product advertising or doing customer service they should be careful, and avoid ambiguity.

@MichaelHarvey For sure. In well-edited copy the meaning is pretty definite.
